# Доступ к файлам на другом жестком диске

Tags: html, ubuntu, html5, xampp

Доброго времени! Такой вопрос, есть сервер в котором установлены 2 жестких диска, один 40 гб, второй 1тб. на 40 гб расположен сервер (xampp сама машинка работает на убунте) и сайт, можно ли каким то образом воспроизводить на сайте файлы со второго жесткого диска (1тб) например аудио

```
<audio controls>
<source src="D:\music\/audio1.ogg" type="audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis">
<source src="D:\music\/audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

каким образом тогда прописывать путь к файлу если такое возможно? Потому что я знаю только как относительно корневой папки сервера оперировать путями, а о том что бы выходит как то за пределы не используя глобальные пути через http я не смог найти

Answer (score 0):

например, вы можете [воспользоваться директивой `alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html), назначив какому-нибудь `url`-у путь к нужному вам каталогу:

```
alias "/music" "/путь/к/каталогу/с/музыкой"
```

---

и затем обращаться к файлам из этого каталога в html-коде:

```
<source src="/music/audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

Comment: и он может находиться на другом жестком диске по отношению к тому где лежит сервер и файлы сайта?

Comment: да, конечно может. собственно, никакой разницы, где файл находится физически, для операционной системы нет. он может быть с таким же успехом располагаться и на другой стороне земного шара.